# Excel add sheet with code after last sheet in Workbook

Tags: vba

I am adding a sheet each month from a sheet called "Template" and namining it "Month Year". That all works fine but it places new sheet next to "Template" sheet. I want it to add new sheet after last sheet in workbook. I changed it to Shhet count but get an error. Can you help?
This is my Code.

```
Sub CopySheet()
   Dim MySheetName As String
   
   'MySheetName = ActiveCell.Text
   'OR
   MySheetName = InputBox("Enter a Sheet Name!")
  
   'check a value has been entered
   If MySheetName = "" Then
      MsgBox "No sheet name was entered, ending!"
      Exit Sub
   Else
      '================================================
      'Check there are no invalid sheet name characters
      '================================================
      If ValidSheetName(MySheetName) Then
       Sheets.Add.Name = "Template"
Worksheets("Template").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
      Else
         MsgBox "There is an invalid character in the sheet name!"
      End If
      
 End If
End Sub




Function ValidSheetName(ByVal sheetName As String) As Boolean
   '========================================
   'check a sheetname for invalid characters
   '========================================
   Dim arrInvalid As Variant
   Dim i As Long
   
   arrInvalid = Array("/", "\", "[", "]", "*", "?", ":")
   
   For i = LBound(arrInvalid) To UBound(arrInvalid)
      If InStr(1, sheetName, arrInvalid(i), vbTextCompare) Then
         ValidSheetName = False
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
   
   ValidSheetName = True
End Function
```

Comment: So you have a template sheet that you're duplicating? If so do `Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)`. Then `ActiveSheet.Name = "New Name"`. That copies the template, moves it to the end, and renames to what you want.

Comment: if the starting sheet index is 0, last sheet index might be Sheets.Count - 1? On the other hand, its better if you share the error you get

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the position of the newly added sheet by

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(<index>)
```

where `<index>` is number from 1 to count of sheets.

This one adds a new sheet to the end the workbook:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

You may consider using an external template file for adding new sheet from a preformatted/prefilled template (.xltx):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count), Type:=<full spec of template file>
```

The template file can contains only 1 sheet.

Sheet addition will implicitly activate the sheet, so you can name it after adding with

```
Activesheet.Name="something"
```

For checking validity of the entered sheet name you can simply let Excel do its job while getting ready for exceptions like

```
On Error Resume Next
Activesheet.Name = MySheetName
If Err.Number = 1004 Then    ' invalid name (wrong char, existing sheetname, zero length name, whatever)
     MsgBox "Invalid or existing sheet name!
Else
     Err.Raise Err.Number          ' other error
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

Notes:

1. Though syntatically correct, sometimes I have trouble with adding a new sheet from template and rename it within one command, that's why I suggest doing it separately in 2 steps: first adding and then renaming
2. PLease note the `On Error` clauses, They are very useful but can easily mislead you when using incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you so much. That has clarified what I am was trying to achieve and works perfectly

Comment: @user3795705 Welcome. Then please accept my answer to indicate that it was useful.